# Можно ли в объявлении функции использовать имена типов, отличные от таковых в определении?

Tags: c++

То есть:

```
int area (int width, int lenght) //Определение
{
return lenght*width;
}

int area (int z, int y); //Объявление
```

И чем это чревато?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас в примере не другие "имена типов", а просто имена переменных другие. На самом деле можно писать даже так

```
int area (int width, int lenght)
{
return lenght*width;
}

int area (int, int); // прототип
```

И это будет работать как ожидается.

А вот использовать другие "имена типов" уже нельзя. Либо не скомпилируется, либо будет работать не так как нужно (зависит от компилятора, но современные компиляторы обычно просто ругаются и не компилируют, если типы и порядок не совпадает).

То есть, вот так уже нельзя

```
int area (int width, int lenght)
{
return lenght*width;
}

int area (int width, string lenght); // прототип
```

Comment: Вы, как и автор, путаете определение и объявление.

Comment: Просто не удалил коментарии

Answer (score 3):

Во фрагменте представленного вами кода это

```
int area (int width, int lenght)
{
    return lenght*width;
}
```

объявление и определение функции, так как задано тело функции,  то есть что она делает. В то время как это

```
int area (int z, int y);
```

всего лишь объявление функции, то есть имя `area` объявляется, как имеющее тип функции `int( int, int )`.

Оба объявления объявляют одну и ту же функцию. Имя параметров не влияют на тип объявляемой функции. Вы могли бы в объявлении функции, которое не является в то же время определением функции, не указывать имена параметров.

```
int area (int, int);
```

Также в C++ можно не указывать имена параметров в определении функции, если эти параметры не используются в теле функции.

Имейте в виду , что квалификаторы верхнего уровня не влияют на тип функции. Поэтому следующие два объявления

```
int area (int z, int y);
```

и

```
int area (const int z, const int y);
```

объявляют одну и ту же функцию, хотя для определения функции присутствующий в объявлении параметров функции квалификатор `const` в общем случае имеет существенное значение.

Также вы должны иметь в виду, что параметры, объявленные как массивы и как функции неявно преобразуются соответственно к указателям на первые элементы массивов и к указателям на функции. Поэтому следующие объявления функций эквивалентны и объявляют соответственно одну и ту же функцию. Учтите, что одна и та же функция может быть объявлена несколько раз в одной и той же области объявлений, но иметь лишь одно определение, если она не является встраиваемой функцией, то есть функцией объявленной со спецификатором `inline`..

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

void init( int a[10], size_t n );

void init( int a[20], size_t n );

void init( int a[], size_t n );

void init( int [], size_t );

void init( int *a, size_t n );

void init( int * const a, size_t n );

void init( int * const, size_t );

void init( int a[100], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a[i] = i;
}

void ForEach( const int [], size_t, void( int ) );

void ForEach( const int [], size_t, void( * )( int ) );

void ForEach( const int a[], size_t n, void operation( int ) );

void ForEach( const int a[], size_t n, void ( *operation)( int ) )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) operation( a[i] );
}

void out( int x )
{
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    int arr[N];

    init( arr, N );

    ForEach( arr, N, out );    
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

В этой программе одни и те же функции `init` и `ForEach` объявляются несколько раз.

Также имейте в виду, что имена, введенные с помощью `typedef` не определяют новые типы. Они лишь являются алиасами для уже существующих типов. Поэтому следующие объявления функции `init` также эквивалентны

```
typedef int TArray[200];

void init( TArray a, size_t n );

void init( int [15], size_t );
```

так как параметры в обоих объявлениях функции преобразуются к типу `int *`